# Read line-by-line file and split values

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to read a txt file composed as follow:

```
      AA=1000,AA=320009#999999

      AA=1011,AA=320303#111111
```

for each readed line I need to split it by "#" to get at the first turn

```
 $test[0] = AA=1000,AA=320009 and $test[1]=999999
```

and at the second turn

```
 $test[0] = AA=1000,AA=320003   $test[1]= 1111111
```

I have some problems to understand how to use get-content or to get it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
# Basically, Get-Content will return you an array of strings such as below:
# $tests = Get-Content "c:\myfile\path\mytests.txt"

$tests = @(
    "AA=1000,AA=320009#999999",
    "AA=1011,AA=320303#111111"
)

$tests | %{ $test = $_ -split '#'; Write-Host $test[0]; Write-Host $test[1] }
```

The line above is equivalent to:

```
$tests | foreach {
  $test = $_ -split '#'
  Write-Host $test[0]
  Write-Host $test[1]
}
```

Meaning that for each line of $tests (each line being materialized by $_, one does a split on '#' (which produces an array used in the Write-Host statements)

Comment: can you explain me better the meaning of "%"?

Comment: %{ ... } is a shortcut for "foreach". Editing the answer to provide equivalent code with foreach.

Answer (score 3):

If all lines in your text file have the same structure, you can use the `-split` operator directly on the result of `Get-Content`:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.txt') -split '#'
```

The result is an array where the even indexes (0, 2, 4, …) contain the first portion of a line, and the odd indexes (1, 3, 5, …) contain the last portion of a line.

Example:

```
PS C:\> Get-Content .\test.txt
AA=1000,AA=320009#999999
AA=1011,AA=320303#111111
PS C:\> $test = (Get-Content .\test.txt) -split '#'
PS C:\> $test[0]
AA=1000,AA=320009
PS C:\> $test[3]
111111
```

Answer (score 3):

other solution:

```
Get-Content "c:\temp\test.txt" | ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter "#" -PropertyNames Part1, Part2
```

Comment: Since Powershell 7.3 there is a `-Delimeter` Parameter inside `Get-Content` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.3#-delimiter