# while read in Powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach

File would look like this

```
Prename Lastname
Prename1 Lastname1
Prename2 Lastname2
...
```

In bash i would read that like this:

```
while read prename lastname do;
echo $prename
echo $lastname
done < text.txt
```

How could i do that in Powershell, i found that so far:

```
foreach($line in Get-Content .\text.txt) {
  write-host $line
}
```

But i need to store the line in multiple variables so i can work with them i dont need the line i need every word seperatet, can someone help me with this or display some documentation?

Greatfull for any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616414/read-line-by-line-file-and-split-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to read the file (assuming the first line contain the "column name") and store it in variable `$fileContent`

```
$fileContent = Import-Csv -Path c:\path\to\text.txt -Delimiter ' '
```

iterate over the content and write out each column (assuming text.txt is separated by space

```
foreach($line in $fileContent)
  Write-Host $line.Prename
  Write-Host $line.Lastname
}
```

also note that if there is a line like

```
firstname secondname lastname
```

`$prename` will be 'firstname'
and `$lastname` will be 'secondname'

Comment: Since the delimiter is ' ' I believe in the example `firstname secondname lastname` `$lastname` would be secondname and the lastname would be ignored/lost.

Comment: that's correct. i updated the comment. thanks.